# JetBrains ReSharper C# Annotation StringFormatMethodAttribute I need an extension method form or custom annotation

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper

Since the extension method FinestFormat() shown below is not in  [System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider,System.String,System.Object[])] form the ReSharper annotation fails to work. Is there an extension method form of this ReSharper 'StringFormatMethod' annotation?

Or can I create my own customer ReSharper annotation to address this scenario? Calling upon ReSharper to carryout its format parms highlighting etc.

```
[StringFormatMethod("formatString")]
public static void FinestFormat(this ILog log, string format, params object[] args)
{
    log.DoLogFormat(log4net.Core.Level.Finest, format, args);
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is. According to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html), the `StringFormatMethod` attribute _"takes a single argument - the name of the format string parameter"_ - which in your case would be `format` rather than `formatString` - or is there a problem with this being an extension method?

Comment: stuartd - you solved it, I was not understanding the correct usage of the attribute parameter "formatstring" which as you point out, should be just "format" in the above code, tested this and it works correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuartd provided the answer, the coding example should have the parameter to StringFormatMethod changed to be "format". He provides link to ReSharper documentation for this as well.

```
[StringFormatMethod("format")]
public static void FinestFormat(this ILog log, string format, params object[] args)
{
    log.DoLogFormat(log4net.Core.Level.Finest, format, args);
}
```